# Pagination - Previous and Next size buttons in jQuery DataTables

Tags: datatables

I need to make my `Previous` and `Next` buttons smaller.
Im using the dataTables plugin alongside bootstrap so the tables are already styled.

Here you can see the involved files [.css and .js](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/tree/master/integration/bootstrap/3)
I've tried twicking them a bit but I can't make it work for me, I can't fing the buttons-related data.

Thanks in advance, any direction you may point would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select those two links by class

```
.previous, .next {
    // CSS here
}
```

[Here](http://live.datatables.net/pafuseb/1/)'s a live version to play with.

Comment: only thing to add is it's .prev not .previous at least according to my files :). Thanks a lot.

Comment: It probably depends on your version of DataTables.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to an old question.

You are probably looking for this. I found it somewhere on Datatable's official site not sure where. But for me the below solution worked:

```
.dataTables_paginate>span>a {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding: 1px 5px !important;
}

.dataTables_paginate>a {
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding: 1px 5px !important;
}
```

Hope it helps someone like me.